# mkfs.ext4 write all over the whole disk?

Tags: mkfs

I it said that  `mkfs.ext4` overwrites data when run over a disk with existing data. My question is, does it really write from beginning till the very end ?  I know that it writes itmaps, inode list, root directory,
lost+found, journal and the beginning but does it wipe the data that's at the disk end ?

Answer (score 1):

No; it only writes what it needs to without trying to zero the whole volume.
Use

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sda
```

to make sure data is gone.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any information about what it needs to write ? Can one then say that the amount of data for a given file system type is fixed? `EDIT` I'm not concerned with zeroing out the volume. I was looking at `drbd` and it uses internal data that gets written to the disk end and next you make a file system on it, was just wondering how does the internal data survive.

Comment: @blablatrace The initial data size is related to the volume size, when you run mkfs.ext4 it will tell you what it wrote and where. you make your drdb on /dev/sdb[1] then your file system on /dev/drbd1 (it's a wrapper/encapsulation)

Comment: ok, so the internal meta data is basically written to /dev/sdb[1] so on the backing device so to say, but the file system is created on /dev/drbd1. Is that what you meant ?